# Did The Wire invent the "Jump 5" cipher?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, ciphers, historical

<sup>N.B. Asking this here instead of *Movies.SE* because I'm wanting to know about the cipher itself and any history, which this site is more suitable for.</sup>

In S01E05 of The Wire, at around 45:00, it's revealed that:

> the gang that the cops are after encrypt their phone numbers by using a substitution cipher based on the layout of a T9 mobile phone keypad.

In [more detail](https://scipython.com/book/chapter-4-the-core-python-language-ii/questions/the-jump-the-five-cypher/):

> Each digit of the number, with the exception of 5 and 0, is replaced with the corresponding digit on the other side of the 5 key ("jump the five''); 5 and 0 are exchanged. Thus, 555-867-5309 becomes 000-243-0751. Devise a one-line statement to encrypt and decrypt numbers encoded in this way.

In the show, this cipher was chosen because it has to be both secure but simple enough for low-level dealers to understand. Is this something that was ever used as a real-life cipher, or anything similar to it, or was it just something devised by the writers?

Comment: This isn't a cipher in the sense we think of them today, since there is no key. It's more like ROT13, which is obfuscation at best.

Comment: I'm aware it's not actually a secure cipher, I just wanted to find out more about where it came from.

Comment: @MechMK1 I would argue that the "13" in "ROT13" is the key.

Comment: "Key" in this context is not a cryptographic key but the literal "5 button" on a numberpad. Hence the `9 -> 1` substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a number pad implementation of the plain old original [scytale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scytale). Using the number 5 key on the pad instead of a rod.

It's a basic substitution cipher.

Was the TV show the first to use the number pad in this way? I cannot answer that. I doubt it.